# Need help installing a local kyma instance

Tags: kyma

i need some help for installing kyma locally.

I was following the official guide:
https://kyma-project.io/docs/kyma/latest/04-operation-guides/operations/02-install-kyma/

I have:

- Windows 10
- Hyper-V activated
- Docker Desktop installed (v4.9.1)
- Kubernetes (1.24.0) - shown by kubectl version --client
- K3d (v5.4.3)
- kyma-cli 2.0.4
- kubernetes-helm 3.8.2

I installed it like this:

1. Starting up Docker Desktop
2. kyma provision k3d
3. kyma deploy

While deploying now, i get some errors, which tell me, that some essential components can not be deployed:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N0mJ.png)

Can you help me solve this so that i can start up a functional kyma instance?

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really sure if this helps but maybe your user installing the software does not have the rights to create a file in that specific folder? Try installing with sudo

Comment: i am installing it on windows and doing it via a administrator started Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.20, Kubernetes deprecated Docker as a container runtime in favor of containerd. Due to a different way in which containerd handles certificate authorities, Kyma's built-in Docker registry does not work correctly on clusters running with a self-signed TLS certificate on top of Kubernetes installation where containerd is used as a container runtime.
If that is your case, either upgrade the cluster to use Docker instead of containerd, generate a valid TLS certificate for your Kyma instance or configure an external Docker registry.
another way is to disable kubernetes provided by docker-desktop and use the command below to provision kubernetes cluster based on k3d

```
kyma provision k3d
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the kubernetes version. After downgrading my docker desktop to 4.1, which is using kubernetes 1.21 it works now.